# Regular expression to match "snnnoooowww" to "snow"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match any number of a certain character within a certain order of characters. In example:

"ssssnnnowww" would match to "snow"
but
"sssnnnsssooooowwww" would not match to "snow"

I have tried the following:

```
/[s][n][o][w]/g // no luck
/s*n*o*w*/ // no luck
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/s+n+o+w+/
```

Comment: ...the idea being that `+` will match one or more of that character.

Comment: aaaaand it's your new top scored answer :)

Comment: Works great, thanks. I did not know about the `+` character. I was trying `*`. I'll tick it as soon as I can.

Comment: @LevLevitsky - With all the effort I put into this post, I most certainly deserve it. =p

Answer (score 1):

Always do remember that `*` is used for zero of more occurrences. So your regular expression `/s*n*o*w*/` would also pass `now`, `sow`, or even just `o`.
so in your case, you need `+` that looks for one or more occurrences.
Correct regex:

```
/s+n+o+w+/
```

Your regex `[s][n][o][w]` would also fail because it looks for exactly a single occurrence of `s` `n` `o` and `w` in the correct order, so would pass `snow`, but would not pass `snnoooow`.